# How to style jQuery progress bar accordingly when it reaches a certain value and also how to remove a certain grayish background?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried the snippet and it is working thanks to all you guys.
But moreover when I try to load the page a grey background is coming.
Why is it so and how to remove it ?
And I want its color to be changed when it reaches a value of say , 50.

my snippet is --

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Progress Bar</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"   />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  //call progress bar constructor    
  $(".text_input_case").keyup(function () {
      var len = $(this).val().length;

      var total = null;
      total = len * 10;

      $("#container").progressbar({ value: len});
  });

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {
    width:auto;
    background-image: url(http://bit.ly/13wIQuG);
 }
</style>


</head>

<body>
<input type="button" class="button_progress" value="Update Progress Bar"/><br />
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="text" class="text_input_case" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update it's css related to `total` value like this

```
$('.ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value').css({
   "background" : (total <= 50) ? "#369" : "#963"
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PWZ9h/)